# How can I play video in React on mouseEnter

Tags: reactjs, html5-video, setstate, mouseenter

I would like to play video on mouseeEnter and pause on mouseLeave. Everytime I try this I get TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined.

When I console.log e.currentTarget I receive correct  tag.

This is what I did so far

```
import { MoviesList, MoviesListEl, Title, VideoWrap, MediaWrap, MovieDesc, MobilePreview } from "./styles"

export default class FetchRandomMovies extends React.Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    movies: []
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const url = "https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topmovies/limit=100/json"
    const response = await fetch(url)
    const data = await response.json()

    this.setState({ movies: data.feed.entry, loading: false })
  }

  getInitialState(e) {
    return {
      isPlaying: false
    }
  }
  mouseEnter = e => {
    this.setState({ isPlaying: true })
    console.log(e)
  }
  mouseLeave = e => {
    this.setState({ isPaused: false })
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) {
      return <div>loading...</div>
    }

    if (!this.state.movies.length) {
      return <div>didn't get movies</div>
    }
    return (
      <MoviesList>
        {this.state.movies.map(item => (
          <MoviesListEl key={item.title.label}>
            <Title>
              <span>{item.title.label}</span>
              <span>{item.category.attributes.term}</span>
            </Title>
            <MediaWrap>
              <img src={item["im:image"][2].label} alt="" />
              <VideoWrap>
                <video onMouseEnter={e => this.mouseEnter(e.currentTarget).play()} controls>
                  <source src={item.link[1].attributes.href} type="video/x-m4v" />
                </video>
              </VideoWrap>
            </MediaWrap>
            <MovieDesc>{item.summary.label}</MovieDesc>
            <MobilePreview href={item.link[1].attributes.href} />
          </MoviesListEl>
        ))}
      </MoviesList>
    )
  }
}
```

Probably on this line is something wrong:

`<video onMouseEnter={e => this.mouseEnter(e.currentTarget).play()} controls>`

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling `.play()` on the wrong value.  You are intending to call `.play()` on `e.currentTarget`, but that's not what your code says.  Your code calls `.play()` on the `void` return from `this.mouseEnter(e.currentTarget)`.

You can fix this a number of ways, the simplest one is to call `play()` within your `mouseEnter` callback.  Since this callback is supposed to take the event, we want to pass it `e` rather than `e.currentTarget`.  But since `e` is the default argument we can just provide our function to `onMouseEnter`.

```
<video onMouseEnter={this.mouseEnter} controls>
```

```
mouseEnter = e => {
    e.currentTarget.play();
    this.setState({ isPlaying: true });
    console.log(e);
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. Using your solution this time I receive:

```'onMouseEnter' is not defined  no-undef```

:(

Comment: Ok Something was wrong with cache I think ? I rerun 'npm start' and now everything is working excellent.

Thank you very much for your time and help :)